# How to lock down a Guest Wi-fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, openbsd

I have a modem/router from my ISP which I'm forced to use. I would like to provide a Wifi AP for random guest that might show up at my house but I don't want to have their virus-laden PC on my network nor do I want them to be able to access anything on my router (which as far as I'm aware is essentially NOT protected) or other computers on the network (which I know are not protected at all).

My first idea was to have an additional OpenBSD router connected to my ISP router, that would in turn encapsulate the "guest" wifi into a VPN (probably IPsec) to a server in a datacenter.

Is that a sensible solution? (I don't mind complexity, just that it's making sense security-wise)

Comment: Learn all about Vlans and implement them.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to purchase another wireless router that has a built-in guest WiFi capability, enable the guest network, and connect it to your existing ISP router. The guest network feature should automatically keep the guest network isolated. If you want more control, you can use VLANS, but you'll need a VLAN-capable switch connected to a router that can handle them. IMHO this would be a bit overkill for a home network, but go for it if you really don't mind the complexity.

Comment: I mostly do this as a learning experiment so that's why I don't mind the complexity. Would a vlan completely isolate the guest wifi, including access to the router web interface for example?

Comment: If configured properly, yes. The router admin interface should "listen" only on the trusted VLAN, making it inaccessible from the guest VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a real firewall as the only device plugged into whatever your ISP gave you.

   a. [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) is free software that works well for this, given hardware with a few Ethernet ports.  You can use an old computer, buy something from the [pfSense Store](https://store.pfsense.org/systems/) , use a tiny PC like a [fitlet XA10](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/order-by-pn/?pn=FITLET-GX-C67-FLAN-W) with 4 Intel ethernet ports, etc.
2. One interface for WAN, one interface to rule them all (LAN), one interface for your wifi.

   b. You could use wifi built-in to a pfSense firewall for this, but I prefer a [Ubiquiti Unifi](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Wireless/bd-p/UniFi) solution - read the forums first, though.  They're very cheap, and very capable, but always read the forums.

   i. Note that the Ubiquiti access points do allow VLAN, as so the pfSense store and fitlet devices, so you could have it serve up four SSID's (one for guests) that are each independent of each other, as well as the management interface.  They need a controller to set this up, either a service on an existing computer, or a Raspberry Pi.
3. On the firewall, for the guest wifi interface or VLAN, it gets its own subnet, and create firewall rules that block it from all other local subnets.  Also create firewall rules that block it from accessing your router directly.
4. Log into the router you were issued, change the password, and turn off its wifi.